# I am unable to understand how match 2 vectors (factor and numeric type), in R?

Tags: r

I am unable to understand how to complete this code in R?
Create a factor vector v1 using 10 random numbers without decimals.
Convert that factor vector to numeric vector v2.
Check if all values in v1 and v2 match respectively. [P.S. : Please use "TRUE" and "FALSE"]

```
v1<-factor(round(runif(10,1,10),digits=0))
v2<-as.numeric(v1)
v1
v2
v1 == v2

n=1
while(n<11)
{if(v1[n]==v2[n]){print(TRUE)}
  else
  {print( FALSE)}
 n=n+1 
}
```

Ans:
v1<-factor(sample(10:40,10))
v1
v2<-as.numeric(levels(v1))[v1]
v2
v1==v2

Comment: I have used the following lines of code:  v1<-factor(round(runif(10,1,10),digits=0))
v2<-as.numeric(v1)
v1
v2
v1 == v2

n=1
while(n<11)
{if(v1[n]==v2[n]){print(TRUE)}
  else
  {print( FALSE)}
 n=n+1 
}

Comment: v1<-factor(round(runif(10,1,10),digits=0))
v2<-as.numeric(v1)
v1
v2
v1 == v2

n=1
while(n<11)
{if(v1[n]==v2[n]){print(TRUE)}
  else
  {print( FALSE)}
 n=n+1 
}

Comment: Please ask a specific question, and not a repost of a broad, general question like this. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It's great that you are trying to add some specific code that you tried. You are able to edit your question and include that information there. That will allow you to format it as well, so that it's more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I have added my code in the question @joran

Comment: Got my answer after a lot of trials:

Comment: v1<-factor(sample(10:40,10))
v1
v2<-as.numeric(levels(v1))[v1]
v2
v1==v2